# Accessing values in third MySQL table in a single combined statement

Tags: mysql

I have a database with three tables in my database namely **catering, room, room_booking** and I am currently access **room** and **room_booking** in the following way - if two conditions are met:

```
SELECT name,capacity,licensed,$price FROM room
WHERE capacity BETWEEN '$minCapacity' AND '$maxCapacity' 
AND room_id NOT IN 
(SELECT room_id
FROM room_booking
WHERE date_booked = '$date')
```

The table **catering** has three columns **room_id,grade,cost**.

I need to select all the fields on table with a matching *grade* as so:

```
SELECT * FROM catering where grade=$grade;
```

How do I add this condition to my main SQL query with the other two conditions intact so that there three conditions in total working together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `JOIN` against `catering`.  Substitute the correct column name for `room.room_id` if that isn't correct (such as if it is supposed to be `room.id`).

```
SELECT name,capacity,licensed,$price
FROM 
 room
 JOIN catering ON room.room_id = catering.room_id
WHERE capacity BETWEEN '$minCapacity' AND '$maxCapacity' 
  AND room.room_id NOT IN 
   (SELECT room_id
    FROM room_booking
    WHERE date_booked = '$date'
   )
   AND catering.grade = '$grade'
```

Not sure why you have used `$price` in the select list. Perhaps that was a typo, or you were substituting a PHP variable?

Comment: I think this explains it: `if ($date_check>=6) {$price='weekend_price';} else {$price='weekday_price';}`!

Comment: I keep getting **MDB2 Error: unknown error** for some reason.

Comment: @CJS did `$grade` need to be quoted as `'$grade'`?

Comment: I've updated some values to use with a read-only table. This is what I have: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/09QC i.e. swapping room for venue.

Comment: @CJS Test that the query itself works in a MySQL client. The MDB2 error is probably some other PHP issue, which is then best asked in a new question that shows the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Wait, I see an issue - the `room_id` in the where clause is now ambiguous because it could be either `room.room_id` or `catering.room_id`. I added the table name to it above.

Comment: It works now! Does this query select the columns **grade,cost** as well?

Comment: @CJS If you need columns from `grade`, just add them in the `select` list. `SELECT name, capacity, licensed, $price, catering.grade, catering.cost`